# Run Scala application on different process

Tags: scala, process

Hi I want to create a program that starts another application on a new process:

```
 object A{
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        Process(????).run
        println("new process has been created")
     }
 }
```

the application that should run on the new process:

```
object B{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    print("Hello world")
  }
}
```

I know I can run a script using Process(script_string_to_run), but I don't know how to make it run another application..

Comment: How is that other application run? However it's run, that's a command, i.e. a string. You can put that string in a script, or execute it as is with `Process(script_string_to_run)`.

Comment: What is another application? Is `B` a part of your code? Then you can run its main method without using `sys.process`. Please, describe your problem better.

Comment: Since the second application (B) is a Scala program, it need to be run as the command-line of a Scala (Java) program: `java -cp one.jar:two.jar some.package.name.B`

Comment: @user2128014 I'm running A directly from Intellij, B should start running after A main method runs Process(....).run. I can't write B in a script because it will have more functionalities then just printing "Hello world". I suppose I can write a script that runs B as a scala application but I haven't had much success in doing that..

Comment: @laughedelic B is under the same package of A, But I want to run it on different process and that A will initialize that process.

Comment: @user2128014 can you give more detailed implementation?

Answer (score 0):

## Run Scala program from another Scala program

## Scala Program

*B.scala*

```
object B {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hello world")
}
```

Now execute the above program like this from another Scala program.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "scala B.scala" !!
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res1: String =
"hello world
"
```

*Note that the file name of the file is same as the object name containing main method. This way scala would recognise the main class/object and execute the main method of the program. If the name of the file is not the name of the object containing the main method then It would not know what to execute.*

`!` gives the exit status of the program after execution whereas `!!` gives the output of the program.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> val status = "scala B.scala" !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
hello world
status: Int = 0

scala> val output = "scala B.scala" !!
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
output: String =
"hello world
```

## Scala Script

Test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala

object B{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    print("Hello world")
  }
}

B.main(Array[String]())
```

Now Just run the B program using

```
"./Test.sh" !!
```

**Command Line Activity**

```
➜  cd demo

➜  demo ./Test.sh
zsh: permission denied: ./Test.sh

➜  demo chmod +rwx Test.sh

➜  demo ./Test.sh
Hello world%                 
                                                                                                                                                        ➜  demo ./Test.sh
Hello world%        
                                                                                                                                                                 ➜  demo scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "./Test.sh" !!
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res0: String =
"Hello world
"

scala> :q
```

Comment: I want B to run from within A. I also will prefer not to change B (with the line B.main(Array[String]())) if possible

Comment: @user_s Yes you can do that

Comment: @pemu I wrote this line in program A : `Process("\"scala DispatcherWorker.scala\" !!").run
` and I've got the error `Cannot run program "scala": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`(the same when I'm running it from cmd)

Comment: @user_s This happens when your `DispatcherWorker.scala` is not in the `path` or in the directory where you are running the program.

Comment: @user_s try to run the program from the same folder where `DispatcherWorker.scala` is available. or Place your `DispatherWorker.scala`  in the dir in which you have started the scala repl

Comment: I did.. A and B are under the same dir. and I'm also running the cmd from the same dir

Comment: @user_s .. try to put the file in the `path` ... system path and see

Comment: which `path` are you talking about? env variables?

Comment: I added the dir(../myProject/src/main/scala) to path but I'm getting the same error

Comment: What is the path of the `DispatherWorker.scala`

Comment: Still not working (I've added the full path c:/workspace/myProject/src/main/scala/B.scala) to the path env variable)

Comment: @user_s the file name has to be the object/class name with main method

Comment: @user_s Try running my code in my answer .. to understand .. what you are doing wrong